# Decorator pattern and type mismatch on ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, decorator

I'm using a decorator class to add some functionality to a model of mine. I only want this information to be used to process some values but not to save anything to the database.

I have my decorator class, something like:

```
class Deco

   def initialize o
     @target = o
   end
   def method_missing method, *args, &block
     @target.send(method, *args, &block)
   end
   #my extra methods
end
```

And I use it like so:

```
deco_model = Deco.new(model)
```

There problem here is when I want to associate this `deco_mode` to another one, I get a type mismatch error, which makes sense, but if I add the following method to my decorator class:

```
def class
   @target.class
end
```

I still get the same error, but it says: Model(#aaaaaa) expected, got Model(#aaaaa)
Yes, the "Model" would be the class of my model, and the object id is the same in both cases... so if the object id is the same, why am I still getting the exception?

Thanks

Comment: It could be even easier to use SimpleDelegator, something like: **class Deco < SimpleDelegator; end**. And no need to write method_missing, and initialiser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I also had to overwrite the `is_a?` method used inside `ActiveRecord::Associaions::Association`

After doing:

```
def is_a? klass
  @target.class.object_id == klass.object_id
end
```

The exception is not being thrown anymore.

Comment: I had another issue with ActiveRecord trying to call `self.primary_key`. I ended up defining `def self.primary_key; 'id'; end` on SimpleDelegator. Hopefully, the api doesn't change again. A friend of mine is taking bets for when I'll have to update the code :D